# Scroll to Top and Scroll to Bottom in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to implement the scroller with top to bottom and bottom to top with jquery. I recently tried with percent.
From the Top to bottom with pixel is seems ok.(Means it works) for the bottom to top is only make scroll not completely finish if i mention percentage as 100

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    var percentageToScroll = 100;
    var percentage = percentageToScroll/100;
    var height = jQuery(document).height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    alert(scroll);
    var scrollAmount = Math.round((height) * percentageToScroll/ 100)-scroll;

    //alert(point);
    alert(scrollAmount);
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount }, 'slow', function () {
                          alert("reached top");    });

});
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qLvC/3/)**.
For Example: 
percentageToScroll is now 100 but the ending of scroll is not completely finish. (from bottom to top)
For top to bottom is 100 then it completely scroll to bottom of the page.

I am not sure how to make it workable.

Thanks.

Vicky

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to implement. But you can use `scrollTop()`

Comment: You should use `console.log(...);` for debugging, instead of `alert(...);` as alert can disrupt your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    var percentageToScroll = 100;
    var percentage = percentageToScroll/100;
    var height = $(document).scrollTop();
    var scrollAmount = height * (1 - percentage);

    alert(scrollAmount);
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount }, 'slow', function () {
                          alert("reached top");    });

});
$('#spnbottom').on("click",function() {
    var percentageToScroll = 100;
    var height = $(document).innerHeight();
    var scrollAmount = height * percentageToScroll/ 100;
    alert(scrollAmount);
     var overheight = jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height();
    //alert(overheight);
jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scrollAmount}, 900);    
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/uz5ER/)

Comment: @jaq316 Quick Question scroll from bottom to top i checked it working fine. For example let consider bottom value as 50%(scroll from bottom to top as 50%) then how it works? From the top to bottom only it take 50% ? If yes means how can i make the scroll from bottom to top as 50%. Hope you got my point ?

Comment: @Vicky Do you mean if the page is scrolled 50% down and you want to scroll to the top?

Comment: No what my ques is we are doing the scroll function as with scrollTop jquery. Let consider from bottom to top as 30% then how it works from the bottom?

Comment: I've updated my answer and the fiddle to answer your question

Comment: Thanks @jaq316 see this fiddle i am not sure this is the testing site height right now i want to scroll from top to bottom with 89 % is not working properly for the bottom to top is working perfect. Let me know what changes shall i need to do for. http://jsfiddle.net/SzuAT/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39744/discussion-between-jaq316-and-vicky)

Comment: Hi @jaq316 Little more help needed Please

Answer (score 2):

As I specified in comment I prepared a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesPJ/nNKdg/2/)

```
$(document).on("click","#spnTop",function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1500);

});
$(document).on("click","#spnbottom",function() {
  var window_height = $(window).height();
    var document_height = $(document).height();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: window_height + document_height },1500);
});
```

I hope it may help you

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#goToTop').on("click",function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
    $('#goToBottom').on("click",function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).innerHeight()}, 2000);
        return false;    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Now see you need the percentages

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3g4d/

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    var percentage = 100;
    var height = $(document).height();
    var remove = +height / +100 * +percentage;
    var spaceFromTop = +height - +remove;
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: spaceFromTop }, 'slow', function () {});
});
```

Comment: I think he needs the percentage part

Comment: I think he want to use the percent (eg: 30%, 73%), this will only work for 100%

Answer (score 1):

I hope something like this `:)` might help you

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    $('html,body').animate(
        { scrollTop: 0 }, 
        'slow', 
        function () {});
});

$('#spnbottom').on("click",function() {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var document_height = $(document).height();
    $('html,body').animate(
        { scrollTop: window_height + document_height }, 
        'slow', 
        function () {});
});
```

Use this link to try it out : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qLvC/7/)

Comment: What about the percentage scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the span positions if you have top and bottom span always.

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:  $("#spnbottom").offset().top
    }, 'slow', function () {
        alert("reached top");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qLvC/8/

Comment: it's about % values, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#scrollToBottom").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: window.screen.height }, 400);
    });
    $("#scrollToTop").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
    });
});
```