# Scroll to Bottom in Jquery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make the scroller with top to bottom and bottom to top simultaneously. I did most of them. From bottom to top is working perfect and for top to bottom only causing somehow problem is works only if i increase the height of the div container. I am not sure where i could change the values to make it workable. 
Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzuAT/)**

**JS**

```
var percentageToScroll = 89;
var height = $(document).innerHeight();
var scrollAmount = height * percentageToScroll / 100;
alert(scrollAmount);

var overheight = jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height();
//alert(overheight);

jQuery("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: scrollAmount
}, 900);
```

I did with percentage to animate the scroll. 
You can click the bottom button in fiddle to see that. I want to scroll only 89% but it scroll fully to the bottom.

Much Appreciated your Help !!!

Comment: I think you need to put the window height in the calculation.

Comment: I alerting the window height value is less compare to document.height When i tried with window height it get complete with middle of scroll even i mention 100 percentage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to Top and Scroll to Bottom in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512871/scroll-to-top-and-scroll-to-bottom-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **top** of the viewport will be at 89% of the document.
If for example your document is 100px in height, the top 89px will be off-screen and the bottom 11px are displayed (for as far as possible). If however you're screen-size is larger than this 11px, it can't scroll down that much.

What you probably want is:

```
var scrollAmount = ($(document).innerHeight() - $(window).height()) * percentageToScroll / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it may helps you

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
       alert("at bottom!");
 }
});

You can also adjust it according to your requirment by reducing its height 


$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-100){
    alert("near bottom!");
 }
});
```